# Akka Cluster in Docker in ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: docker, akka, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, akka-cluster

I am trying to set up an Akka cluster in docker, in ElasticBeanstalk. The nodes must communicate with each other like so:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ElasticBeanstalk/ECS                                  |
|                                                       |
| +----------------------+     +----------------------+ |
| |  EC2                 |     |  EC2                 | |
| |                      |     |                      | |
| | +------------------+ |     | +------------------+ | |
| | |  Docker          | |     | |  Docker          | | |
| | |                  | |     | |                  | | |
| | |  +------------+  | |     | |  +------------+  | | |
| | |  |            |  | |     | |  |            |  | | |
| | |  |            +---------->->-->            |  | | |
| | |  |  Akka      |  | |     | |  |  Akka      |  | | |
| | |  |            <--<-<----------+            |  | | |
| | |  |            |  | |     | |  |            |  | | |
| | |  +------------+  | |     | |  +------------+  | | |
| | +------------------+ |     | +------------------+ | |
| +----------------------+     +----------------------+ |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using the information in the blog posts [Akka Cluster EC2 Autoscaling](http://chrisloy.net/2014/05/11/akka-cluster-ec2-autoscaling.html) (which doesn't include Docker) and [Akka Cluster in Docker](https://hackernoon.com/akka-cluster-in-docker-a-straight-forwards-configuration-b6deea32752d) (which doesn't include EC2) I've put together an *almost there* solution.

The final hurdle is comms between the nodes. Each node correctly identifies the internal IP of the other. I assume the EC2 instances can communicate directly, bypassing the ECS load balancer.

The akka nodes are listening on port 2551.

```
/app # netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 :::sunproxyadmin        :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 d0a81ebbe72a:2551       :::*                    LISTEN
```

The docker instances are exposing port 2551.

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d0a81ebbe72a        mystuff/potter:v1.0.7-cluster04       "sh -c 'java -jar -Xm"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:2551->2551/tcp   ecs-awseb-maptiles-dev-uicd96apyp-6-potter-b8d6a7aef2c4c9c0a001
d6bc31f1798b        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest        "/agent"                 About an hour ago   Up About an hour                             ecs-agent
```

The EC2 instances have a security group which allows incoming connections on port 2551.

```
良 aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "i-0750627a98ba930d4" "i-0bcd64a4121165327"|jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].SecurityGroups[]'
{
  "GroupName": "akka-remoting",
  "GroupId": "sg-6c267e16"
}
{
  "GroupName": "akka-remoting",
  "GroupId": "sg-6c267e16"
}

良 aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-names akka-remoting | jq -c '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions'
[{"PrefixListIds":[],"FromPort":2551,"IpRanges":[{"CidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"}],"ToPort":2551,"IpProtocol":"tcp","UserIdGroupPairs":[],"Ipv6Ranges":[{"CidrIpv6":"::/0"}]}]

良 aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-names akka-remoting | jq -c '.SecurityGroups[].IpPermissionsEgress'
[{"PrefixListIds":[],"FromPort":2551,"IpRanges":[{"CidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"}],"ToPort":2551,"IpProtocol":"tcp","UserIdGroupPairs":[],"Ipv6Ranges":[{"CidrIpv6":"::/0"}]}]
```

But still the nodes cannot see each other.

```
[INFO] [08/23/2017 23:31:37.227] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [08/23/2017 23:31:37.805] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://potter@172.31.12.161:2551]
[INFO] [08/23/2017 23:31:37.818] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://potter)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://potter@172.31.12.161:2551] - Starting up...
[INFO] [08/23/2017 23:31:37.867] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://potter)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://potter@172.31.12.161:2551] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [08/23/2017 23:31:37.867] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://potter)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://potter@172.31.12.161:2551] - Started up successfully
[WARN] [08/23/2017 23:31:38.053] [New I/O boss #3] [NettyTransport(akka://potter)] Remote connection to [null] failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.31.35.149:2551
[WARN] [08/23/2017 23:31:38.056] [potter-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.tcp://potter@172.31.12.161:2551/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fpotter%40172.31.35.149%3A2551-0] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://potter@172.31.35.149:2551] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://potter@172.31.35.149:2551]] Caused by: [Connection refused: /172.31.35.149:2551]
```

What have I missed/misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the advice in the AWS forum post [Single Docker Container with multiple open ports](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=213341), setting Akka's `akka.remote.netty.tcp.bind-hostname` to `0.0.0.0` instead of the local IP enabled comms.